# separate radio group zf2

Tags: php, html, zend-framework2, radio-button

Within my application I have a 3 steps registration form. In part one someone has
to select a package (member ship).

Here I need one group of radio buttons but because I am handeling 3 packages with each
2 options, with a lot of html between each 2 radio buttons I need to separate the
radio buttons and getting them one by one. the separate option for this is probably not
enough because it's not consistent with html and there can be a lot of html between.

Thanks! =)

Comment: can you upload some sample code?

Comment: What's wrong with just, ya know, using html? There's no rule stating that forms must be rendered by view helpers.

Comment: I did it on this way by now. I set the data before validation :)} w

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using js `hide-show`

```
<script>
    $(function(){
       $("#package1").on(click,function(){
           $("#p1").show();
       });

       $("#package2").on(click,function(){
           $("#p2").show();
       });

       $("#package3").on(click,function(){
           $("#p3").show();
       });
    });
</script>

<style>
    .hidden {
       display: none;
    }
</style>

<input type="radio" name="package" id="package1" value="Package1">
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package2" value="Package2">
<input type="radio" name="package" id="package3" value="Package3">

<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p1" name="p1option" value="P1 Option1">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p1" name="p1option" value="P1 Option2">

<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p2" name="p3option" value="P2 Option1">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p2" name="p2option" value="P2 Option2">

<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p3" name="p1option" value="P2 Option1">
<input class="hidden" type="radio" id="p3" name="p3option" value="P2 Option2">
```